# I want Show my own App icon in the lower-left corner of iPhone Lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

can please give me some Suggestions? Like this﻿[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't control what app appears in the bottom-left corner of the lock screen.  Neither can you add code to your app to make your app appear there whenever you want.  These are called *Suggested Apps* and it's a feature of iOS.

iOS controls what app appears there based on several factors, including your location, the apps on your device, and your history of where & when you use those apps.  Together, iOS *trys* to present you with the app you would most-likely use at a given time, location, and history.

If you don't like this feature, it can be turned off in `Settings -> General -> Handoff & Suggested Apps`.

Comment: If that answer helped you, please be sure to [accept](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.  This will allow others with the same problem find answers to their questions.